# Unable to set specific tablet active area mapped to 1 of my 2 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, xinput, graphics-tablet

I use a graphics tablet to play a game called osu! and it's important for me to have a specific region of the tablet mapped to the monitor for comfortable play. With only 1 monitor it works fine. But, if I have 2 plugged in, my tablet's active area spans the 2 monitors. I have tried to use the `xinput map-to-output` command and that maps to my primary monitor just fine, but it loses the tablet area that I need and resets it to full active area. After trying to set my area again it just goes back to spanning 2 monitors, this isn't what I want.

The command I use to set my tablet area is `xinput set-prop "UGTABLET TABLET G3 5x4 Pen" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.7 0 -0.4 0 1.688 -0.2 0 0 1`